# PayPal iOS SDK response Shipping Address: (null)

Tags: ios, paypal, sdk, paypal-sandbox

#### Information

- Mode (Mock/Sandbox/Live): Sandbox
- PayPal iOS SDK Version: 2.14.3
- iOS Version and Device (iOS 8.x, iOS 9.3 on an iPhone 6s, etc.): Simulator iPhone 5 iOS 9.3

#### Description

```
_payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
_payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;
```

In payPal controller I choose Shipping Address (PayPal account address). But in response I get Shipping Address: (null).

```
CurrencyCode: EUR
Amount: 416.99
Short Description: Clothes
Intent: sale
Processable: Already processed
Display: €416.99
Confirmation: {
    client =     {
        environment = sandbox;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "2.14.3";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    response =     {
        "create_time" = "2016-06-23T12:54:24Z";
        id = "PAY-3H962440US5*******";
        intent = sale;
        state = approved;
    };
    "response_type" = payment;
}
Details: Subtotal: 299.99, Shipping: 117, Tax: (null)
Shipping Address: (null)
Invoice Number: (null)
Custom: (null)
Soft Descriptor: (null)
BN code: (null)
Item: '{Some|299.99|EUR|(null)}'
```

Why I get response Shipping Address: (null)?

Answer (score 0):

You get nil because you should provide shipping address in PayPalPayment.shippingAddress. This is written in SDK help

`/// - PayPalShippingAddressOptionBoth: user will choose from the shipping address provided by your app,
///   in the shippingAddress property of PayPalPayment, plus the shipping addresses on file for the user's PayPal account.`

**UPDATE**
if you want to get address from paypal try to use these option:

```
PayPalConfiguration *configuration = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
        configuration.merchantName = @"Name";
        configuration.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;
```

if you want to provide it by yourself use something like that:

```
PayPalConfiguration *configuration = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    configuration.merchantName = @"Name";
    configuration.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionNone;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = amount;
    payment.currencyCode = @"RUB";
    payment.intent = PayPalPaymentIntentSale;
    PayPalShippingAddress *shippingAddress = [PayPalShippingAddress shippingAddressWithRecipientName:recipientName withLine1:address withLine2:nil withCity:city withState:nil withPostalCode:postalCode withCountryCode:countryCode];
    payment.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But if I set  _payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal; And choose Shipping Address then I get  'Shipping Address: (null)' too. I need choose address from payPal account, not from app address

Comment: I need get response Shipping Address from payPal chosen account address

Comment: If you want to choose address from paypal try to set PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal.

Comment: Yes, I try. But I get 'Shipping Address: (null)' too.

Comment: Look 
_payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
_payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;

I get response 'Shipping Address: (null)'